# Print or echo verable data inside html with a function

Tags: php

I'm trying to print or echo my html part, then print a bit more html through a function, then print the ending html. When I do this the middle part is always printed or echoed outside of the intended html code. The only way I seem to be able to fix the problem is cut the code up and run the function inside the code directly... so in other words this does not function correctly, but why and how to solve problem...:

```
$ORthefunctioinname = functionstuff($yeah);
echo '<html>' . thefunctioinname($yeah) . $ORthefunctioinname . '</html>';
```

Anyone know how to solve this to make the function print the html inside the html code as written without having to cut up the code and write the whole function code inside the html?

Example correct result:

```
<html><more html></html>
```

Comment: have you tried removing '<html>' and '</html'> from your echo? (assuming that `<more html>` is the result of the function)

Comment: Going to take a guess that your functions both `echo` their data instead of returning it. There's an ancient duplicate floating around here somewhere...

Comment: OK got it. To solve the problem use ```return 'stuff';``` in the function instead of ```echo 'stuffbad';```. Thanks.